# Version comments in Workflow comments

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

When someone checks in a document which then publishes a major version. Is there any way to get the comments of the last document version and insert them into the workflow comments?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SharePoint Designer (SPD) to Create a Workflow that could copy the Check In Comments into another field whenever a document is created or updated.

You would need to create a new field in the document library eg. "All Check In Comments"

Then go to SPD create a new List workflow for the document library.

Create a workflow variable (Set Workflow Variable) to store the current value from "Check In Comments"

Then set the "All Check In Comments" field (Set Field in Current Item) with the value of the variable you created.

To prevent the field from being overwritten you will want to click the `...` button in value section to open the String Builder.

Then you'll need to add lookup for "All Check In Comments" and the workflow variable with the current Check in Comments.

```
[%Current Item:All Check In Comments%]

[%Variable:CheckInComment%]
```

The string builder will look something like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this same issue. In my experience using SharePoint online 2013, this is not a valid option as "Check In Comments" is not a selection available in order to populate the variable.